# Excel - PivotTable - Show top 10 while subtotal shows sum of all records

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I remember seeing this done before and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Would like to setup the pivot table to show only top 10 records, but show the complete sub total for all records (at "the top").

Thanks!

Comment: My default pivot automatically does that. Selected Top 10, with subtotals at top. Design as Compact Form.

Answer (score 1):

Please see capture below! Right click and look into the pivot table options

[image]